# PFX file without import password?

Tags: tls, certificates, pfx

Is it possible to create a pfx file without import password? Or is it possible to remove the import password from pfx file that I've already created?

Comment: Dupe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/195080/how-to-convert-my-cert-chain-to-pfx-without-a-password

Answer (score 12):

> Is it possible to create a pfx file without import password?

Yes, it is possible:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout PrivateKey.pem -out Cert.pem -days 365 -nodes

openssl pkcs12 -export -out keyStore.p12 -inkey PrivateKey.pem -in Cert.pem
```

> Or is it possible to remove the import password from pfx file that
>   I've already created?

Yes, it is possible:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in old.pfx -nodes | openssl pkcs12 -export -keypbe NONE -certpbe NONE -out new.p12
```

Conversion from .p12 format to .pfx format is possible by just renaming the file.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow. Good job. That `-keypbe NONE -certpbe NONE` stuff looks like undocumented behavior. It's neither in https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-pkcs12.html nor in https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-pkcs8.html

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff What? Undocumented behavior for openssl? Nah... Impossible.

Comment: @dim: yeah. Perish the thought, right? ;)

Comment: The direct pipe only works if old.pfx has the keybag before the certbag; this is not standardized and different file-creators vary. If you do `openssl pkcs12 -in old -nodes >temp && openssl pkcs12 -export <temp ...` it always works, because temp can be re-read from the beginning; or you can do `( openssl pkcs12 -in old.pfx -nocerts -nodes; openssl pkcs12 -in old.pfx -nokeys ) | openssl pkcs12 -export ...` to force the key to be first.