# How to create PKCS12 container with no password

Tags: openssl, ios, 802.1x, wpa2-eap, pkcs12

I have set up 802.1x authentication on my wireless network with EAP-TLS.  The use case here is that I would like the presence of a certificate to be both necessary and sufficient for connecting to the network.  The condition is that there should be **no passwords of any kind** involved in any point of the authentication process.

After generating the client certificate, I used openssl 1.1 to generate a .pfx file in PKCS12 format (the server certificate is different and is signed by Let's Encrypt to avoid requiring clients to trust the server CA).  I sent it to my Android device, installed it as a wifi certificate, and it worked great.

Today I had a guest come by who wanted to connect using an iPhone.  They were able to download the certificate (iOS seems to call it a profile), but when they went to import it, it asked for a password.  The interface would not allow them to enter a blank password, the "Install" button would be greyed out unless they typed something.  We could not figure out any way to convince iOS that the certificate had no password, nor a blank password.  [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497723/export-a-pkcs12-file-without-an-export-password#comment71662109_27497899) seems to indicate that doing so is not possible.

I then tried the steps mentioned in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/515842) which gave the same result.  I tried following the steps in [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/218964/200790) but when piping the certificates, all I got was the error `unable to load certificates`.  I thought `-keypbe NONE -certpbe NONE` might be the important part so I regenerated the .pfx file from scratch and added those parameters, but with the same result (iPhone prompted for password).  Lastly I saw in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/195231/200790) the `-nomac` flag, so I tried adding that, but this time the iPhone refused to load the certificate at all (errored with "Invalid Profile").

I am using openssl 1.1 to avoid any of the algorithm issues with openssl 3.  How can I generate a PKCS12 container with no password that is accepted by iOS devices?

Comment: Re #218964/218969: the direct pipe `openssl pkcs12 -in old -nodes | openssl pkcs12 -export -certpbe NONE -keypbe NONE [-nomac] -out new` only works if old file has keybag before certbag, which varies depending where it's from; if you instead create a temp file `openssl pkcs12 -in old -nodes >temp && openssl pkcs12 <temp -export ...` it works always (but leaves a file with your key which you need to securely delete), and so does `( openssl pkcs12 -in old -nocerts -nodes; openssl pkcs12 -in old -nokeys ) | openssl pkcs12 -export ...` (but you must enter pw twice).

Comment: However `-keypbe NONE -certpbe NONE -nomac` IS correct for no password at all, and if iOS doesn't accept that there's  nothing else you can do.

Comment: You could create a version of the pkcs12 file *with* a password; you only need to enter the password on the iPhone once (when installing the certificate), not each time it's used.

Comment: Thanks all...looks like there may not be a way to do this.  However I was looking on the [Apple help site](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/distribute-certificates-depcdc9a6a3f/web) and it says "If the payload contains the password, the identity can be installed without prompting the user for it."  What feature is this referring to - is there a way to embed a password?  How can I use this with openssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did manage to solve this and wanted to share the solution here for anyone attempting the same use case.  What I did was export the certificate with an extremely long password, then create a [.mobileconfig file](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/configuration-profile-enforcement-secf6fb9f053/web) with the certificate and password embedded in it.

From a threat model perspective, this .mobileconfig file is functionally the same as the unprotected certificate used for Android clients.  The password in question will never have to be entered by a human.

At first I attempted to write this file by hand using the Apple documentation, but found that any mistakes, either syntactic or semantic, result in the same useless "Invalid configuration profile" message.  So I borrowed a Mac to use [Apple Configurator 2](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id1037126344?mt=12).  The steps are as follows:  create a new profile of type Certificate and attach the PKCS12, including the password (the app requires you to enter a password here, so there really is no way to distribute a passwordless PKCS12).  Then create a profile of type Wifi and enter the details including SSID, whether you want to enable autojoin, etc.  Add both these profiles to a new blueprint, export that blueprint to a .mobileconfig, and then distribute that, and it works!  There are several places where the user will have to accept an untrusted connection, that you could probably cut down on, but I did not bother.

My final .mobileconfig is as follows (sensitive parts redacted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>PayloadContent</key>
        <array>
                <dict>
                        <key>AutoJoin</key>
                        <true/>
                        <key>CaptiveBypass</key>
                        <false/>
                        <key>DisableAssociationMACRandomization</key>
                        <false/>
                        <key>EAPClientConfiguration</key>
                        <dict>
                                <key>AcceptEAPTypes</key>
                                <array>
                                        <integer>13</integer>
                                </array>
                                <key>TLSMaximumVersion</key>
                                <string>1.2</string>
                                <key>TLSMinimumVersion</key>
                                <string>1.2</string>
                        </dict>
                        <key>EncryptionType</key>
                        <string>WPA2</string>
                        <key>HIDDEN_NETWORK</key>
                        <false/>
                        <key>IsHotspot</key>
                        <false/>
                        <key>PayloadCertificateUUID</key>
                        <string>[REDACTED UUID]</string>
                        <key>PayloadDescription</key>
                        <string>Configures Wi-Fi settings</string>
                        <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
                        <string>Wi-Fi</string>
                        <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
                        <string>com.apple.wifi.managed.[REDACTED UUID]</string>
                        <key>PayloadType</key>
                        <string>com.apple.wifi.managed</string>
                        <key>PayloadUUID</key>
                        <string>[REDACTED UUID]</string>
                        <key>PayloadVersion</key>
                        <integer>1</integer>
                        <key>ProxyType</key>
                        <string>None</string>
                        <key>SSID_STR</key>
                        <string>[REDACTED SSID]</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                        <key>Password</key>
                        <string>[REDACTED PASSWORD]</string>
                        <key>PayloadCertificateFileName</key>
                        <string>[REDACTED FILENAME]</string>
                        <key>PayloadContent</key>
                        <data>
                        [REDACTED CERTIFICATE BASE64]
                        </data>
                        <key>PayloadDescription</key>
                        <string>Adds a PKCS#12-formatted certificate</string>
                        <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
                        <string>[REDACTED FILENAME]</string>
                        <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
                        <string>com.apple.security.pkcs12.[REDACTED UUID]</string>
                        <key>PayloadType</key>
                        <string>com.apple.security.pkcs12</string>
                        <key>PayloadUUID</key>
                        <string>[REDACTED UUID]</string>
                        <key>PayloadVersion</key>
                        <integer>1</integer>
                </dict>
        </array>
        <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
        <string>Untitled</string>
        <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
        <string>[REDACTED NAMESPACE]</string>
        <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
        <false/>
        <key>PayloadType</key>
        <string>Configuration</string>
        <key>PayloadUUID</key>
        <string>[REDACTED UUID]</string>
        <key>PayloadVersion</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

There you go, passwordless wifi for iOS clients.  As a bonus, this same .mobileconfig also works for macOS clients - just distribute it on a USB stick or something.